# ImportError: cannot import name 'Container' from 'collections'

Tags: python, heroku, collections, containers

My code is running fine in local, but crashes on Heroku. What can I do to fix it?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last)
   File "/app/nao_entre_em_panico.py", line 2, in <module>
     from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
     from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
     __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 71, in <module>
     from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 27, in <module>
     from werkzeug.http import HTTP_STATUS_CODES, \
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 1148, in <module>
     from werkzeug.datastructures import Accept, HeaderSet, ETags, Authorization, \
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 16, in <module>
     from collections import Container, Iterable, MutableSet
 ImportError: cannot import name 'Container' from 'collections' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Container`, `Iterable`, `MutableSet`, and other abstract base classes are in [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc) since Python 3.3.

Comment: from collections.abc import Container dind't work

Comment: You edited `/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py`? What was the new error?

Comment: Can you update `werkzeug` to the latest version? This has been fixed in [the source](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/main/src/werkzeug/datastructures.py#L6-L7).

Comment: Upgrade requirements.txt Werkzeug==0.14.1 to Werkzeug, now works, thanks!!

Comment: @MattDMo how do you edit `/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py`. I mean how can you access it?

Comment: @SabzalievShukur I'm not sure what you're asking. You change to that directory in your terminal and edit the file with your favorite text editor: nano, pico, vi, emacs, ed...

Answer (score 2):

Update werkzeug to the latest version:

`pipenv update werkzeug`
or
`pip install --upgrade werkzeug`